# Why is "appreciate" pronounced as though the "c" is an "sh"?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is it that "appreciate" is pronounced as though it were "appreshiate?"

Comment: It isn't, at least around here (western US).

Comment: @jamesqf: how do you pronounce it? "a-PREE-see-eight"?

Comment: The penultimate syllable is typically pronounced (in the US) as either "she" or "see", or possibly somewhere in-between.  Even a given speaker may not be consistent, varying with the context and the speed/casualness of speech.

Comment: Are you asking why the 'c' is pronounced as a 'sh' and not a 's' or ar you asking why it isn't pronounced as a hard 'c', that is closer to a 'k'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, English words spelled with "ci", "ti" or "si" before a vowel letter are often pronounced with a "sh" sound /ʃ/ rather than a "s" sound /s/. This phenomenon is called "palatalization," and it is described in the answers to the following questions:

- [How to pronounce to differ spatial from special?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16856/how-to-pronounce-to-differ-spatial-from-special/16878#16878)
- [What rules of English allow the first t in “patient” to make an sh sound?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4737/what-rules-of-english-allow-the-first-t-in-patient-to-make-an-sh-sound)
- [Is there a simple guide for 's' vs 'sh' pronunciation in words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270549/is-there-a-simple-guide-for-s-vs-sh-pronunciation-in-words?rq=1)

The answers I linked to above mostly discuss words like *social* /ˈsoʊʃəl/ and *initial* /ɪˈnɪʃəl/ where there is no distinct "i" sound after the /ʃ/. However, there are also some words where "ti" or "ci" before a vowel letter is pronounced as /ʃi/, the combination of the "sh" consonant and a short unstressed "ee" sound (in some older British dialects, the sound used in words like this was more like "ih"). This includes words like *associate* (v.) /əˈsoʊʃieɪt/, *appreciate* /əˈpriːʃieɪt/, and *initiate* (v) /ɪˈnɪʃieɪt/.

It seems that this pronunciation is used for words ending in *-iate,* as well as further derivatives of these such as words ending in *-iation.* More generally, a pronunciation with /ʃi/ often seems to be possible when the following vowel letter represents an "unreduced" vowel sound like /eɪ/, /oʊ/ (*ratio*), /ɒ~ɑ/ (*preciosity*), /ɛ/ (*conscientious*), or /æ/ (*partiality*).

For some of these words, a pronunciation with /si/ is also possible; you should check a dictionary to see if that is the case for any particular word. For example, the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary lists an alternate pronunciation with /si/ for *[associate](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/associate_1?q=associate),* but not for [*appreciate*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/appreciate?q=appreciate) or *[initiate](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/initiate_1?q=initiate).*

Another reason to check the dictionary: some words with similar spellings are never pronounced with /ʃ/, such as [*pronunciation*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pronunciation?q=pronunciation) and *[calcium](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/calcium?q=calcium),* for which the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary lists only the pronunciation with /si/.

By the way, this kind of palatalization can also affect many other words such as those spelled with "ce" (*ocean*); it generally occurs in words spelled with *t, c, ss, s,* or *z* or before *i* or *e* followed by another vowel letter (a non-exhaustive list of possible environments for palatalization: "ia", "ie", "io", "iu", "ea"), resulting in pronunciations with fricatives like /ʃ/ or /ʒ/.

When "t" comes after the letter "s", it doesn't palatalize to /ʃ/ but to /tʃ/ (as in "Christianity" /krɪstʃiˈænɪti/). This rule also applies to [words ending in *-stion*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279239/what-are-the-rules-to-pronounce-the-suffix-tion-in-english-t%CA%83%C9%99n-or-%CA%83%C9%99n), like "question" /kwɛstʃən/.

Another, slightly different kind of palatalization occurs in words spelled with *ss, s, z, t,* or *d* before unstressed "long u" (often in the ending "-ure"), resulting in pronunciations with fricatives like /ʃ/ or /ʒ/ or affricates like /tʃ/ or /dʒ/.

Comment: In retrospect, the oddest example of pronouncing a 'c' as 'sh' in my experience is the way people in southeast Texas (where I grew up) pronounced 'grocery': as a two-syllable word with a long 'o' in the (stressed) first syllable and a long 'e' in the second syllable, as if the word were spelled 'groash-ree'. Compare that to the pronunciation of 'groceries' by Jerry Reed (who grew up in Atlanta, Georgia) at 0:57–1:00 of his song '[Amos Moses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7GyLr7Cz2g)', where there is at least a hint of a mushy 's' sound in the word.

Comment: @SvenYargs, that's exactly the pronunciation I grew up with in DeKalb, IL (right on the isogloss bundle separating Northern from Midlands).  /'groʃristor/ three syllables.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this video. It seems that you can also pronunce it as in "see".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y55l-3pnV7s

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Not a bad start, enjoy the site.